# codeigniter pagination url and display issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i have a problem with my pagination in CI. 
my url for the first page: http://example.com/products/page 
second page: http://example.com/products.page/12 than 24 and so on +12

Controller:

```
$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "shop/page";
$config["total_rows"] = $this->shop_model->products_count();
$config["per_page"] = 12;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
$config["num_links"] = round($choice);

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data['products'] = $this->shop_model->
getProducts($config["per_page"], $page);
```

and if i insert and:

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

Model:

```
function getProducts($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('products_img', 'products_img.i_product_id = products.id', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by("products.id", "desc");
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

it shows me the url corectly, but it displays almost the same products that were on the first page.

I checked and other posts on this kind of problems, but i couldn't solve it. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit doesn't care about the page, it cares about the result to start with:

```
function getProducts($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('products_img', 'products_img.i_product_id = products.id', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by("products.id", "desc");
    $this->db->limit($limit, ($start * $limit));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It displayed "almost the same" results because you were only offsetting by 1, or 2, or 3 if the page number were 1, 2, or 3..

The above assumes that page 1 is actually 0 though, page 2 is 1, etc etc.. Did that because you default to zero. If that isn't the case you should adjust to reflect what you represent page numbers as.

Comment: but how do I change to make that page 2 remains page 2?

Comment: $default page to 1 instead of 0.. then do $this->db->limit($limit, (($start-1) * $limit)); instead of the code above

Comment: You are setting it in your shorthand if statement: $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

Comment: God, I messed up my mind with all of this and didn't noticed a simple thing. thank you man very much!